# Exposing aggregation through the interface vs. delegation

Tags: design-patterns, interface, aggregation, delegation

I have an *Employee* object which aggregates a few other objects, such as *HRData* and *AssignmentHistory*. In the past all of this logic was contained directly in the *Employee* object, but for testability and manageability I've split it to use aggregation. However, instead of exposing the aggregate objects directly, I've used delegation so that clients would be kept unaware of the internal working. For example, instead of doing this:

```
employee.getHRDataOn("2010-01-01").getProfile();
```

Clients would do this:

```
employee.getProfileOn("2010-01-01");
```

I really liked this because it followed a "black box" approach, which meant that I could change the implementation at will without affecting the clients, while still consisting of small, testable objects internally. Problem is the *Employee* object has grown considerably, as it now has 5 aggregate objects, and it's interface is littered with *getXXXOn()* methods.

Which approach do you use and why? Is there an alternative that I overlooked? My problem with using the delegate approach is that the interface becomes massive, and my problem with exposing the aggregate objects is that the code is less flexible and that the client needs to know which aggregate is responsible for what. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing Employee to provide a GetEmployeeDataOn(Date) method, and a class for EmployeeDataOnDate that stores this date and has methods like GetProfile().

Comment: Thanks for answering. Perhaps I don't understand you correctly, but this would not address the littered interface problem, would it? If there are 20 getXXXOn() methods, the new EmployeeDataOnDate object will still have 20 getXXX() methods.

Comment: Sure it will.  But you're enacpsulating them away from other Employee behaviors, like DoSomeWork() or GoOnStrike() or whatever and putting this collection of methods about getting an employee's records on some object that is about that.  It helps cohesion, and the SRP.  Many methods are not in themselves a problem, if you manage them appropriately to your needs.